# Evaluate an infinite series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate this $$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}}$$where $b, c, d, e$ are positive real numbers that guarantee the series converges, and $b>d>1$ and $c>e>1$.

I encountered this problem when solving a model which I build by myself so I am unsure if there is a neat solution. Any suggestion can be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since $b>d>1,\,c>e>1$, what I can do is to find a lower and upper bound of the sum.

From

$$0<bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}\leq bc^{t-1}$$
we get a lower bound
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}}\geq \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{bc^{t-1}}=\frac{c}{b(c-1)}.$$

We must be more careful with the upper bound. 
$$bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}=de^{t-1}\left(\frac{b}{d}\left(\frac{c}{e}\right)^{t-1}-1\right).\tag 1$$
Starting with certain $t_0$ (for $t\geq t_0)$ is $\frac{b}{d}\left(\frac{c}{e}\right)^{t-1}\geq 2.$ Then from $(1)$ we get $$bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}\geq de^{t-1}.$$

If we had $t_0=1,$ we could write
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{bc^{t-1}-de^{t-1}}\leq \sum_{t=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{de^{t-1}}=\frac{e}{d(e-1)}.$$ Unfortunately, I do not see how to find a better estimate or a closed form of the sum, since no further information about $b,c,d,e$ is given.